# Surface sdk 2.0 keyboard not showing in application

Tags: c#, keyboard, surface

I am trying to show the keyboard when I click a button, but it's not showing a keyboard at all.
The "TEST" gets printed but the keyboard isn't showing.
My code is :

```
private SurfaceTextBox mySurfaceTextBox = new SurfaceTextBox();

void showKeyBoard(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Focus((IInputElement)getCanvasFromButton((SurfaceButton) sender));
        System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Focus((IInputElement)mySurfaceTextBox);

        Console.Write("TEST");

        SurfaceKeyboard.IsVisible = true;
        SurfaceKeyboard.CenterX = (float)InteractiveSurface.PrimarySurfaceDevice.Bounds.Width - (SurfaceKeyboard.Width / 2);
        SurfaceKeyboard.CenterY = (float)InteractiveSurface.PrimarySurfaceDevice.Bounds.Height - (SurfaceKeyboard.Height / 2);
        SurfaceKeyboard.Layout = Microsoft.Surface.KeyboardLayout.Alphanumeric;
        SurfaceKeyboard.Rotation = (float)(Math.PI / 2);
        SurfaceKeyboard.ShowsFeedback = false;
    }
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the surface framework; but usually you cannot force a keyboard to appear, the focused object needs to accept text as an input.

Because buttons generally don't accept text input, the keyboard's focus cannot be given to it, and thus

```
System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Focus((IInputElement)sender);
```

will be ignored.

If the idea is to only make the keyboard appear, then an option is to add a `SurfaceTextBox` and to give focus to the textbox (this will inturn remove focus from the button)

### XAML

Add this to your XAML file

```
<Canvas>
    <s:SurfaceTextBox 
    Name="yourSurfaceTextBox"
    Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="200"
    Width="100" Height="40" />
</Canvas>
```

### Code File

```
void showKeyBoard(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write("TEST");

    System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Focus((IInputElement)yourSurfaceTextBox);

    // Rest of your code...
}
```

If the idea is to get navigation between buttons, you should consider using a `SurfaceListBox` since it accepts as a default behavior arrow navigation from the keyboard, then your code above should work.

### Question in Comments

*How I can test this on a non-surface device?*
You can use a [simulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804952(v=surface.10).aspx) which should be included in the [2.0 sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=26716)

*How I can change the cursor position in the SurfaceTextBox to the place it's touched?*
I don't really understand what you mean by 'place it's touched', but you can change the cursor location in the textbox using the select method.

```
yourSurfaceTextBox.Select(position, 0);
```

To get the touch locations you can use

```
ReadOnlyTouchPointCollection touches = touchTarget.GetState();
```

Then you'll have to figure out where in relation to an object the touch was, but I this question is beyond the scope of the original question.

Have fun!

Comment: Can you test this in microsoft visual studio 2010 if it works? Or will the keyboard only appear on a touchscreen with surface sdk?

Comment: The on-screen keyboard doesn’t automatically appear if you’re using a desktop app. Instead, you need to tap or click the Keyboard icon for on-screen keyboard on the right side of the taskbar. - http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/touch-mouse-and-search/how-to-use-the-on-screen-keyboard

Comment: Could you check my new code? I've editted the question. Should this work now?

Comment: When I try that code on my desktop (windows 8, microsoft visual studio 2010) and tap the keyboard icon, the keyboard doesn't popup after clicking the button. Test still gets printed.

Comment: Yes I tried it, but maybe there is something wrong with the configuration of the device, thats why I ask you if that code should work? :) Because then I know I need to change some settings of the device.

Comment: I don't have a surface device to test on, but the **private** SurfaceTextBox will not give the desired results. Move it to the actual 'surface' and check if it brings the keyboard. If that works, then you should be able to figure out something ;-)

Comment: Ok I changed the code now, is there a way on how I can test this on a non-surface device? Else I need to go to the university for every small change. Thanks already, I've accepted your answer.

Comment: By the way do you know how I can change the cursor position in the SurfaceTextBox to the place it's touched?